# accessing text in tkinter button for use in command

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am creating a keyboard in TKinter. pressing a button should just print out the text for that button. For some reason every button prints out ctrl which is the last button created. How do I change it so that it actually prints out the respective text for each button?

```
 def press(key):
     print(key)

 def createWidgets(self):
    for tup in layout.layout:
        for key, value in tup:
            button = Button(self, text=key, command=lambda: self.press(key))
            self.kboard_buttons.append(button)
            button.pack(side="left")
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Could you paste the entire code into a gist at https://gist.github.com/ and post the link here?

Comment: I can see wrong only in `print(key)` that is misindented, if such a word exists...

Comment: Could you please try `lambda k=key: self.press(k)` and let us know of your findings?

Comment: Well, iCodez flashed a similar answer while I was writing my comment so I'm now pretty sure my suggestion was correct!

Comment: @JayronHubbard The answer by iCodez below is both correct and helpful, really helpful with regard to your misunderstanding, the gist is not really necessary any longer.  Go and approve... Ciao from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression inside a `lambda` function is evaluated when the function is *called*, not when it is defined.  This means that the `key` in:

```
command=lambda: self.press(key)
```

will always refer to the last value held by `key` in the for-loop.

You can fix this problem by simply capturing the value of `key` as a default argument for the `lambda`:

```
command=lambda key=key: self.press(key)
```

Because default arguments are evaluated when a function is defined, this will ensure that the `key` inside the `lambda` refers to the current value of `key` inside the for-loop and not the last value.

Comment: Thank you! Would you also be able to explain to me why my keyboard looks so out of whack? I'm trying to make it look like a real keyboard. I posted a link to the github in one of my comments.

Comment: You need to play around with your arguments to `grid` in order to space the buttons correctly.  For example, removing  `columnspan=value` makes things look a lot better.  Other than that, it is just a matter of tweaking the values of the arguments.  Here is a reference on the available arguments to configure the behavior of `grid`: http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: Additionally, you should never call `grid` on the same line as you create a widget because `grid` always returns `None`.  So, `kboard_buttons` will be a list of `None` in the end.

Comment: But I need some of the keys to be different columnspan such as the enter and space key. The correct column span should be the value i set it to so I'm not sure why that screws things up. So wouldn't I have to call grid when I create the widgets?

Comment: What I mean is don't do something like `button = Button(...).grid(...)` because `button` will be assigned to `None`.  Instead, do `button = Button(...)` and then on the next line `button.grid(...)`.